Not able to Copy File to a longer path on Jenkins?
I am using the following code to copy a file from a local path to a destination which is a long path on Windows. This works fine on local machine but somehow fails on Jenkins with error code 0x3. I would appreciate some tips to debug,
Thanks in advance.
   // Define the source and destination paths
   const wchar_t* sourcePath = L"SOMETarFile/SomeFile.data";
   const wchar_t* destPath = L"SOMETarFile/"
                             L"LongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryL"
                             L"ongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectory/SomeFolder_.datafiles/"
                             L"Turbocharger/SomeFile.data";

   // Define the destination directories
   const wchar_t* destDirs[] = 
   {
       L"SOMETarFile/LongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectory",
       L"SOMETarFile/LongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectory/SomeFolder_.datafiles",
       L"SOMETarFile/LongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectoryLongPathDirectory/SomeFolder_.datafiles/Turbocharger"
   };

   // Create the destination directories if they do not exist
   for (const wchar_t* dir : destDirs)
   {
       if (!CreateDirectoryW(dir, NULL) && GetLastError() != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
       {
           QFAIL("Failed to create the destination directory. Failing the test.");
       }
   }

   // Copy the data file to a folder with a long name
   // If the copy fails then the test is failed as
   // this copy operation is vital to run the test
   if (!CopyFileW(sourcePath, destPath, FALSE))
   {
      wprintf(L"Format message failed with 0x%x\n", GetLastError());
      QFAIL("Failed to copy the file. Failing the test.");
   }

   


A side note: why are you not using the standard std::filesystem::create_directory and std::filesystem::copy_file ?

From documentation: "By default, the name is limited to MAX_PATH characters. To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, prepend "\?" to the path." MAX_PATH is 260. Trying to find a duplicate, can't believe it haven't been asked before...

What's with this "SOMETarFile/"? Are you attempting to copy out of/into a TAR archive using CopyFileW?

MSDN: Maximum Path Length Limitation

This type of path is composed of components separated by backslashes in Maximum Path Length Limitation. Are Forward slashes equal to backslashes in Jenkins?
